# AVAudioPlayer Swift simultaneously play two audio

Tags: ios, xcode, swift, audio, avaudioplayer

My question is: I am using one ViewController and the choice of songs and there lose. How to make it so that if I clicked on the enable next previous audio has stopped. And it turns out that simultaneously play two audio recordings and new and previous.
This is my code:

```
var audio = AVAudioPlayer()

func playDownload(previewUrl: String) {
  if let url = localFilePathForUrl(previewUrl) {
    let playerItem = AVPlayerItem(URL: url)

    do {
      audio = try AVAudioPlayer(contentsOfURL: url)
      try AVAudioSession.sharedInstance().setCategory(AVAudioSessionCategoryPlayback)
      try AVAudioSession.sharedInstance().setActive(true)
      audio.delegate = self
      audio.prepareToPlay()
      audio.play()
    }
    catch {
      print(error)
    }    
  }
}
```

Comment: Why did you declare an `AVPlayerItem` when using the `AVAudioPlayer`? And I usually do this by writing it as                                                                        `do {
            try AudioPlayer  = AVAudioPlayer(contentsOfURL: ButtonAudioURL, fileTypeHint: nil)
        } catch {
            print("errorin do-try-catch")
        }`

Comment: Ok, before you start palying the second song, did you call `audio.stop()`? At the beginning of the `playDownload(...)` function

Comment: Yes of course, I using audio.stop()

Comment: When using AVAudioPlayer, in order to play multiple sounds, you need to create another instance of the AVAudioPlayer and load it with the new URL resource

Comment: Any luck? if not I like to help, let me know